# Foreign Keys: Multiple Numeric or Character

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have to store records in a "Analyze" table which are referenced to a Object with a defined Id (nvarchar20).

I came up with two possible designs (see Option A or B) for the Analyze Table:
What I'm not sure about is weather its better to store the primary key of the different objects (ObjectA, ObjectB, ...) in separate columns or simply store the plain ObjectId

The Analyze Table is growing very fast and most operations are read via a given ObjectId. So most cases you have a ObjectId and have to search the Analyze Table.
The pattern of the ObjectId is always the same: for example you can identify a given ObjectIds Type if you look at the eight to fourth last characters CA16834K2385**0001**ABCD
**0001** is always ObjectA 
**0002** is always ObjectB

ObjectA

```
| PK (bigInt) | ObjectId (nvarchar20) | otherfields |
| ------------| --------------------- | ------------|
| 1           | CA16834K23850001ABCD  | ..          |
| 2           | CA16834K23850001ABCE  | ..          |
```

ObjectB

```
| PK (bigInt) | ObjectId (nvarchar20) | otherfields |
| ----------- | --------------------- | ----------- |
| 1           | CA16834K23850002ABCD  | ..          |
| 2           | CA16834K23850002ABCE  | ..          |
```

Option A:
AnalyzeTable

```
| id (bigInt) | ObjA_PK (bigInt)| ObjB_PK (bigInt)| otherfields... |
| ----------- | --------------- | --------------- | -------------- |
| 1           | 1               | NULL            | ...            |
| 2           | NULL            | 1               | ...            |
```

Option B:
AnalyzeTable

```
| id (bigInt) | ObjectId (nvarchar20)       |  otherfields... |
| ----------- | --------------------------- | --------------- |
| 1           | CA16834K23850001ABCD        | ...             |
| 2           | CA16834K23850002ABCD        | ...             |
```

What is the better design for reading the AnalyzeTable. Since numeric indexes might be faster than an index on an nvarchar?

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're asking. Why do you have different tables for different customers? How do the rows in the "RecordTable" relate to the rows in the other tables? Also, what do you mean by "database performance"? Speed of writes (for what kind of operation)? Speed of reads (for what kind of access)? Disk space (for what scale of data)?

Comment: With performance I mean the the speed of reads and finding Entries in the Record Table by searching with the ObjectId. The ObjectId in the Record Table is a ForeignKey to one of the Customer Tables.

Comment: It would be useful to [edit] your example to show a more representative set of data, and how you would want to access it. The ObjectId "CI13834K2385RHT50001" doesn't appear in either of the "Customer" tables, but "CA16834K23850001ABCD" appears in both, so I'm not sure what Option B actually represents.

Comment: Also, to clarify my first question: having different tables for different customers is very unusual, and usually a "smell" that something is poorly designed elsewhere in the schema. The most common answer to this question would be "neither of the above": the Record table would contain a foreign key that unambiguously referenced a single table. It may be you have good reasons for that part of your design, but your description is too abstract to understand what the actual requirement here is.

Comment: As a final point, your title doesn't really reflect the question: the main difference between the two options presented is not whether they use a BigInt or a VarChar as their foreign key, but how they represent the possibility of referencing two different tables.

Comment: The smaller the FK the faster the queries used to be. Nowadays there's no much difference between a `BIGINT` (8 bytes) and a `NVARCHAR` (20-40 bytes). Both options seems to be good enough for me. Now, if you include the queries you want to optimize, then we will have a much better idea of the challenge you are facing, and can help you accordingly.